# Common modulus attack with not coprime exponents

Tags: rsa

lets suppose we have the public keys $(n,e_1)$ and $(n,e_2)$, such that $\gcd(e_1,e_2)=d>1$, and the same message encrypted with these two keys.

I'm trying to see if common modulus attack on RSA can be adapted to these problem where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are not coprime, but I always get stuck at some point where I should calculate a discrete logarithm, which is obviouslly not viable in an attack to a cryptosystem.

Any ideas about if it is possible this adaption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (or so we hope).  If you could, you could break RSA.

Suppose you had an Oracle that, given $n, e_1, e_2, m^{e_1}, m^{e_2}$ with $\gcd(e_1, e_2) = d$, and which is able to output $m$.  We can assume that the Oracle only works for a specific $e_1, e_2$ pair.

Then, suppose you were given $c = m^d$, and wanted to recover $m$.  Here is what you could do:

- Compute $c_1 = c^{e_1/d}$, and $c_2 = c^{e_2/d}$

We note that $c_1 = m^{e_1}$ and $c_2 = m^{e_2}$.

- We give $n, e_1, e_2, c_1, c_2$ to our Oracle; our inputs matches the Oracle requirements and so it produces $m$, thus solving the original RSA problem.

Comment: This (nicely) proves that the oracle can solve RSA with public exponent $\gcd(e_1,e_2)$. It does not prove that the oracle can help solve RSA with large random public exponent.

Comment: @fgrieu: no, it doesn't.  However, solving the RSA problem for any public exponent $> 1$ would be an advancement...